# flex action script the text field is missing ctrl+v paste?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flash

i have a flex action script web app, i which i am adding a custom item in context menu to copy the link of the post.

1. the link that is copied is made internal to the app using deep linking
2. i am using a UItextfield to show some titles of posts and a UIComponent is containing it only to show the hand cursor on title field
3. the title field when right click the user can copy the link of the post
4. the title field has `mousechildren = false` and `uicomponent` containing it has `buttonmode = true`

**Problem:**

when user copy the link of the post by right click, the ctrl+v will not work then for a single time and on pressing another time it works normally, only 1 time after copy link it is missed, i get the event of ctrl+v but it do not paste text in any text field in my app.

i found the other copy paste works nice only copy link will produce this problem and even after copy link i can paste by right click paste,

i also found the if i press any single key in any text field this problem will not occur and every thing works fine

i also tried by `mousechildren = true` for title text field it then works fine.

i have this problem only when `mousechildren = false` for title field and then right click copy link and want to directly paste then link in any text field without any key press in any text field

i am not able to understand this behavior help required
regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i find this and solved the problem

1. By `mouseChildren = false` the flash player can't find the component under the cursor as i contains the text field in a uicomponent and text fields mouse children is false so flash player gets the component under cursor as uicomponent
2. by making `mouseChildren = true` this issue is solved and every thing works fine
3. so i changed the approach to get hand cursor on title by changing `Mouse.cursor = MouseCursor.AUTO;` and `Mouse.cursor = MouseCursor.BUTTON` as per need it solves this problem

Answer (score 0):

`this.stage.focus = titleText;` after the link is copied to clipboard (when the context menu is closed) should help